# GIT Restore Misunderstanding

Tags: git, restore, staging

I have been reading the official GIT manual and I am working to understand the `git restore` command which is supposed to replace part of the functionality of `checkout`, I believe. Anyway, here is where I am at:

1. I edit a file in my working directory called git.md
2. I then stage the file but continue to make modifications to the `git.md` file in my working area. I decide that I want to revert back to the file in the staging area.
3. I use the `git restore git.md` and it replaces the current `git.md` with the snapshot of the one in the staging area.

Works as intended. Next scenario:

1. I make some changes to git.md and stage it but realize that I want to replace it with a snapshot of the `git.md` file in my last commit.
2. I run `git restore --staged git.md`
3. I check the file and all of the changes I made to the file are still there and it's currently in the working area.

I was expecting to see the staged git.md replaced with a snapshot of the last committed `git.md`.

Question, Is this how it is supposed to work or should it have replaced the staged `git.md` with the one in the last commit?

Comment: @axiac I edited the question to fix the error you pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The introduction to [the manual page for git restore](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) says, in part:

> Restore specified paths in the working tree with some contents from a restore source.
> ...
> The command can also be used to restore the content in the index with --staged, or restore both the working tree and the index with --staged --worktree.

So, the `--staged` argument specifies the *target* of the command as *only* the staging area (index).

The *source* of the file to restore is specified by the `--source` argument, but with different defaults based on the target:

> If not specified, the contents are restored from HEAD if --staged is given, otherwise from the index.

So, the two common options are:

- Neither of `--staged` or `--source` specified, restores working copy from the staging area. In effect, it "undoes" any local changes which haven't been staged.
- `--staged` specified but not `--source`, restores the staging area from HEAD (the currently checked out commit). In effect it "unstages" any changes which haven't been committed.

To restore both the staging area *and* the working tree from the current commit, it is necessary to specify both `--staged` and `--worktree`, and to explicitly state the source.

The manual gives this example:

```
git restore --source=HEAD --staged --worktree hello.c
```

And this rather cryptic abbreviated form:

```
git restore -s@ -SW hello.c
```

As I understand it, this is equivalent to running the two default modes one after the other:

```
git restore --staged   # target staging area, implicit source HEAD
git restore            # implicit target worktree, implicit source staging area
```

As a final note, I see the manual states that this command is still "experimental". It's possible it will be tweaked in future and this scenario will become easier (or just different).

Comment: Your example above is exactly how I understood it to be. Like you said, it might need to be tweaked.

Comment: I will try the first option and see if that works for staged files.

Comment: I used git restore --source=HEAD --staged --worktree  myfile and it worked as it should. Thank you.